# Json issue when migrating from elasticseach 6 to 7

Tags: json, elasticsearch

we use elasticsearch to power our classified search engine [Listings360 Kenya](https://listings360.co.ke/).

In Elasticsearch version 6 during the search we could get the total hits documents count used for pagination here from this json output

```
Array
(
    [took] => 3
    [timed_out] => 
    [_shards] => Array
        (
            [total] => 5
            [successful] => 5
            [skipped] => 0
            [failed] => 0
        )

    [hits] => Array
        (
            [total] => 30540
            [max_score] => 
            [hits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
```

Now the exact same search with elasticsearch 7 give the following json output

```
Array
(
    [took] => 14
    [timed_out] => 
    [_shards] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1
            [successful] => 1
            [skipped] => 0
            [failed] => 0
        )

    [hits] => Array
        (
            [total] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 10000
                    [relation] => gte
                )

            [max_score] => 
            [hits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
```

You can see that i don't have the [hits][total] anymore which is used for pagination purpose.

Any idea how to get that back

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jap, that´s one of the [breaking changes in 7.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html).

Have a look at the search param `track_total_hits` which forces the count to always be accurate. Nevertheless, the new format will still apply and you need to patch your application (that's why it's a breaking change).

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#hits-total-now-object-search-response) is more detailed info regarding the new response structure.

Comment: thank you very nuch i added "track_total_hits" => true, and now it is working. Thanks